# Calling Microsoft Graph API results with OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use this sample code https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample to talk to GraphAPI but when request is being sent I'm just getting OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound (in an exception 401 unauthorized).

[image: Authentication error]

I went through readme, step by step, and recheck already dozens of times to make sure that clientId, tenantId, secret are valid. Even decoded JWT token to make sure that's valid.

Googling it doesn't really helped. Does anyone have may have an idea what's changed to GraphAPI since this sample code have been provided?

I'm using currently Azure 30-days free plan.

App registration permissions given:
[image: Permissions]

Cheers

Comment: You said you're using Azure 30 day trial - do you have Microsoft 365 (Exchange Online, Office, etc.)? That error could indicate you don't have those services.

Comment: As @Jason Johnston suggested you need to check if you have proper license and check if you have provided the correct tenant I'd in the app code.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

In scenarios where you are working with Office 365 and exchange, your app needs to be registered in the same AD as your exchange or Office365.As Jason rightly pointed out, please try out in an account with the said privileges' and provide your feedback.